Missing Visual Studio 2019 library when building with application with enable address sanitizer turned on in Visual Studio 2022
When building my application (win32 exe) with Visual Studio 2022, I get a link error:

Cannot open input file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x86\clang_rt.asan_dbg-i386.lib'


Looks like your project has a hardcoded path to Visual Studio 2019 installation that's maybe not there any more. Open the vcxproj file with a text editor and try to locate that and fix it

I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://github.com/FASTSHIFT/X-TRACK/issues/77

Used notepad++ to search all files in both the library and the application folder, but no reference found. Even searched the registry.
